# Maven, build a submodule separately

Tags: maven

I have a multimodule project. Root module has `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

When I try to build whole project - it works fine. When I try to build a module that has no dependencies to other modules from my project - works fine. When I try to build a module that dependent on other project submodules - it fails with message

```
Failed to execute goal on project controller:
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.template:controller:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to collect dependencies for [***full list of dependencies***]:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.template:model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
Could not find artifact org.template:root-module:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Seems that it misses pom for root module

Here is part of the submodule pom, that linking to the root module

```
<artifactId>controller</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.template</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-settings</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../root-module</relativePath>
</parent>
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: I found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module