# Multi module build artificant resolutions vs. individual build?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have observed the following maven behavior in my project which does not make sense to me. Here is the essence of what is going on.

Lets say I have a project with with two modules

- com.example.foo.jar
- com.example.bar.jar bar depends on foo
- both share a common parent project that is includes maven module

When my local .m2 is empty and therefore foo and bar are not installed.

- In the `project/` directory `mvn clean verify` works and the build is successful
- in `bar/` directory `mvn initialize` does not work and I get an error message saying that maven could not resolve bar's dependency on foo

So why can maven build the project when I invoke it from the project folder but not from an individual module?

```
project/
  pom.xml
  foo/
    pom.xml
  bar/
    pom.xml
```

I am trying to avoid the `mvn install` hack discussed here http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2012/12/maven-and-hack.html

Comment: does the project pom include foo as a dependency with a version?

Comment: @jtahlborn yes dependencies are explicit so bar has an explict dependency on foo in the bar pom.xml with version number set to be ${project.version}

Comment: include the relevant parts from your poms (modules and dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

You can build submodules in the reactor:

```
mvn -pl bar package -am
```

You'll need to include `-am` to also build `foo`, as otherwise Maven has nowhere to get `foo`'s `jar` from.

See [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module) for more details.