# "Child-only configuration" in parent POM / NOOP Parent POM

Tags: java, maven

I have a project *generating code*. The generation takes really long, so I've split it in multiple projects, each generating 20% of the whole. The original POM became the "parent POM", and the children depend on it, containing only an individual artifact ID, and one or two changed properties.

I *don't want* to "build the parent", so that it delegates to the children, as this takes too long. I only want to build the children individually. So I don't have a "modules" part in the parent.

Now this works, except for one thing: Maven puts in the child POM in the repository that they are *dependent on the parent*. But the parent by itself effectively *doesn't exist*. The parent never gets executed and does not produce any artifact. I can't even execute the parent, because it fails due to "missing files" and such. The plugin configuration in the build section is really *only for the children*; there is *nothing to do* to build the parent, since it doesn't really exist as an artifact.

Can I either remove the dependency of the children artifact on the (non-existing) parent artifact,
OR
Somehow mark the whole of the parent POM (build/plugins, build/resources and build/pluginManagement) as "ignored" when the parent itself is built? (Hopefully resulting in only a POM for the parent in the local repo)

What I would like is "reuse without dependencies", but that doesn't seem possible (I don't understand why; the child jar clearly does NOT depend on the parent jar, only the child *POM* depends on the parent POM).

I've also seen examples where a POM was generated from a "template" (eliminating the dependency), but that is not useful to me either, since I would have to re-generate each child POM when the *parent template* changes.

Maybe it would make more sense to me, if I understood why *POM dependency* is hardwired to imply *artifact dependency* in Maven?

To use an analogy, when I build a dog-house, I "depend" on the wood, and the hammer, ... to do it. But once the dog-house is built, the dog-house, itself, does not depend on the hammer to be used anymore.

Comment: I found out I could "work-around" it, by temporarily "emptying" the parent POM, so it "builds", and installing that in the Maven repo, but that is just a really ugly hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have nothing in the parent but modules, dependencyManagement and build/pluginManagement, and you should reference the children from the parent via a modules section (if you want to build one module use -pl and -am ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module)). Your pluginManagement section should contain all plugins with common configuration, scopes and versions. Your dependencyManagement section should contain all dependencies, scopes and versions. Your child poms should contain no versions, and scopes for dependencies that are different from the parent, and the plugins that are needed to build the specific module.

If you have something different from this, then try this and see if it works, then please report back with the problems for further analysis.

Comment: Too late to try it today, but I still have a question: I read that pluginManagement only affects the children *if they explicitly declare using the plugin themselves* (in other words, pluginManagement configuration in the parent doesn't "move to build/plugins" in the child). Assuming this is correct, I would still have to declare the parent plugins in the build section in the children (which I'm not doing atm). Am I correct?

Comment: I've done it slightly differently, but it worked. I find having the dependencies directly in the parent doesn't cause issues, so I did not put them in dependencyManagement, since that would have required me to duplicate them in the children too. I moved the parent POM "next" to the children instead of "on top" of them, so the resources directories would be valid in the parent too (same directory depth). They do not seem to be causing issues either anymore. I would have liked an option where the plugins were not mentioned at all in the children, but the artifactId alone is "small enough".