# Maven partial Install

Tags: maven, maven-reactor

Is there a way to selectively specify which modules to install while building a complete reactor project?

In essence I would like to package the complete reactor content but only install a few.

Comment: That sounds strange can you describe more in detail what you like to achieve and how your project look like and why you are trying to go that way?

Answer (score 0):

There are many option that allow you to manage a modulare project in maven.

**To Resume Build**

> The -rf or --resume-from option can come in handy if you want to tell the Maven Reactor to resume a build from a particular project.This can be useful if you are working with a large multimodule project
>   and you want to restart a build at a particular project in the Reactor without running through all of the
>   projects that precede it in the build order.

**Example** mvn --resume-from yourmodule install

**Specifying a Subset of Projects**

> The -pl or --projects option allows you to select a list of projects from a multimodule project. This
>   option can be useful if you are working on a specific set of projects, and you’d rather not wait for a full
>   build of a multi-module project during a development cycle.

**Example** mvn --projects yourmodule1,yourmodule2 install

**Making a Subset of Projects**

> If you wanted to run a portion of the larger build, you would use the -pl or --projects option with
>   the -am or --also-make option. When you specify a project with the -am option, Maven will
>   build all of the projects that the specified project depends upon (either directly or indirectly). Maven will
>   examine the list of projects and walk down the dependency tree, finding all of the projects that it needs to
>   build.

**Example** mvn --projects sample-services --also-make install

You can find more detail on [Maven: The complete references](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/pdf/mvnref-pdf.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the swift replies; Alas I am well aware of all documented reactor options and indeed use them in conjunction with profiles specifying modules subset but I was hoping for a more elegant way of achieving it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GuySegev From that that you wrote I understand that you don't knew how to manage reactor with modular project. For more details try to explain us your real problem

Answer (score 0):

No; a single invocation of Maven will use the same phases for all modules.

You could chain invocations; for example:

```
mvn package && mvn -pl web-app install
```

But then the dependencies of `web-app` would be taken from your local repository and not from the reactor used in the first invocation.

The safest option would be (as in [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module)) to use `-am` and `-pl` to install only a specific module along with all its dependencies:

```
mvn -pl web-app -am install
```

Note that this will still install other modules, but only those necessary to build `web-app`.