# Maven: Two projects with common dependency - recommended project structure?

Tags: maven, multi-module

I have project which consists of two separate sub-projects and some common code, with the sub-projects needing to be built independently.

What would be the recommended Maven project structure for this scenario?

I've already tried something like this:

```
-project-parent
   -pom.xml
-projectA-parent
   -pom.xml
-projectA
   -pom.xml
-projectB-parent
   -pom.xml
-projectB
   -pom.xml
-common
   -pom.xml
```

The parents for A and B are responsible for building the modules projectA/common and projectB/common. In the project parent POM I would define some common dependencies.

Is there an alternative that does not use a parent hierarchy? Something that, e.g., uses build profiles which can be used to build either projectA or projectB with their dependencies (common)?

Comment: Why does the projectA-parent has the dependency on common, when projectA depends on common?

Comment: projectA-parent does not have "common" as a dependency, it only declares it as a module so it gets build whenever projectA is build.

Comment: Then add all dependencies to projectA

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the accepted answer of [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module).

So you may need just one parent for all modules an then use the pl-option to select the modules for the build.