# Springboot 2.3 with Docker. I want to build image for a specific app when I have multiple springboot applications in same repository

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, buildpack

Building a springboot application version 2.3. I want to build a docker image with the cloud native build packs. I have 2 springboot applications sitting inside my repository, say App A and App B. Usually, I do mvn install, pick up the jars and start them individually. Run jar "a" for aapp a and jar "b" for app b. Now,  How do I tell the build pack on which jar I want to build my docker image on.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Simply start mvn spring-boot:build-image

Comment: What tool are you using to run the build? `pack` or another platform like `kpack`?

Comment: I would also like to raise the question why you have 2 runnable Spring Boot applications inside one repository. I'd like to shape my Git repositories according to the deployment later. If you deploy them separately (which I assume) it's maybe time to think about refactoring both into seperate repositories... And if there's code to share, you'd might end up having a 3rd repo for that, which produces a Maven module which is used by the others.

Answer (score 2):

Building on a [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3899772/1384449) of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26439938/1384449) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54697431/1384449), you can use the [advanced reactor options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) to target a single module in the reactor and build the image just for that module.

A command like

```
mvn -pl <module-name> -am spring-boot:build-image
```

will likely give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever platform you're using, you should be able to point the build toward your relevant subdirectory. For instance, if you're using `pack`, you can use `pack build -p <repo dir>/<app A dir>`. Depending on which Java buildpack you're using, it should run Maven for you and set up the resulting JAR to launch when the app image is started.