# Maven: Build shared Module as Dependency for other Modules so the can be build separately

Tags: maven, dependencies

I've got a multiproject with several Modules (Microservice Modules), this Modules have a same codebase etc. persistence layer. Which i would like to extract in a separate Module (Shared Module).

The structure looks like:

```
Main Pom
  |- Microservice 1
  | |- module 1
  | |- module 2
  |- Microservice 2
  | |- module 1
  | |- module 2
  |- Microservice 3
  | |- module 1
  |- Shared Module
```

I know that i can add the "Shared Module" as a dependency to the "Microservice Modules", but than I can only build the hole project by building from the main pom.

But i want to build the Microservices Modules separately. Is it possible building the Shared Module before building only one Microservice Module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module)

Comment: If you have defined the dependencies between your Microservice and the shared module correctly the shared module will be build before all other MS...which is the default behaviour of maven...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the shared module as dependency for others modules.

Then, add a `<modules>` section (if not already exists) in main pom and list all modules.

Then, you can build only shared module from main pom by doing:

```
mvn install -pl :shared-module
```

Or you can build all modules by doing:

```
mvn install
```

Or you can build only module1 and theses dependencies (ie shared-module) by doing:

```
mvn install -pl :module1 -am
```

Or you can also list all projects you want to build manually:

```
mvn install -pl :shared-module,:module1
```