# Maven Mutliple Project Hierarchy with several projects based on the same core but without aggregation

Tags: java, maven, module, pom.xml

I have 5 projects in my workspace, 2 of them are core projects and 3 are implementing these core projects.

Core Projects:

- OnlineToolCore
- OnlineToolCoreImpl

Implementing Tool Projects:

- ToolAImpl
- ToolBImpl
- ToolCImpl

I want the possibility that if I build ToolAImpl, that OnlineToolCore and OnlineToolCoreImpl are also builded before without building ToolBImpl and ToolCImpl.

The same for ToolB: Core but not ToolA and ToolC. And for ToolC: Core but not ToolA and ToolB

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I understand your question, but not the reasons. Are you using Eclipse? If so, you can use workspace resolution to always resolve dependencies to the latest version in your workspace.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module You can specify to build a single module and the modules it depends on with `mvn clean package -pl ToolAImpl -am`. That would build `ToolAImpl` and Core (assuming it depends on core). And it wouldn't build ToolB or ToolC.

Comment: That Response from Tunaki helped. Thank you very much.