# How to call <script> from maven

Tags: maven, ant

I have some script to call from my maven pom.xml to perform selective build for my projects.
below is the script which I  want to call from maven.

```
`<script language="javascript">
          var projectArr = selectiveProjects.split(",");
          for (var i = 0; i &lt; projectArr.length; i++) {
            //dynamically creates antcall task
            var task = project.createTask("antcall");
            //set target attribute value
            task.setTarget(project.getProperty("target"));
            //creates param element
            var param = task.createParam();
            //set param name attribute
            param.setName(project.getProperty("param"));
            //set param attribute value
            param.setValue(projectArr[i].trim());
            //execute the ant call
            task.perform();
          }
        </script>`
```

Any help or workaround to call script or to perform selective builds from maven  will be appreciated..

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Comment: You don't use such scripts in Maven. You let Maven do the build.

Comment: Can you suggest some ways to perform selective builds from maven using paremeters? @JFabianMeier

Comment: Does this you mean you want to build only some projects of a multi-module project? What parameters do you mean? Could you give a concrete example?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple projects from a multimodule project and I have to build only a few using their individual poms Ex: I have to build only 2  projects from  <module>app/authorization</module>
        <module>app/taskmanager</module>
        <module>app/cxaudience</module>
        <module>app/rimobile</module>
        <module>app/collaboration</module>
        <module>app/shorturl</module>
        <module>app/icr</module>
        <module>app/icrmigration</module> @JFabianMeier

Comment: You can build some of the modules by using `-pl` parameter on command line

Comment: can you share some examples for the same @JFabianMeier

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3899772/927493