# How do I get maven to build nested sub modules?

Tags: maven

I have module setup:

```
grandparent -> parent -> child1
      \               -> child2
       \
        --> child3
        --> child4
```

I would like to build everything under parent.

I have tried:

```
mvn install --projects ":parent"
```

but that only builds parent, and none of the submodules of parent.

The modules are setup correctly because

```
mvn install
```

builds all submodules.

For now my workaround is to enumerate all submodules of parent:

```
mvn install --projects ":parent,:child1,:child2"
```

This differs from [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module) because:

1. Here I have three levels are parent projects. The suggested question only has two levels.
2. -am (also make) would build too much in my case because child2 depends on child3. I only want child1 and child2 built (parent can be built or not built. I don't care about that one).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven Modules + Building a Single Specific Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114026/maven-modules-building-a-single-specific-module)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I learned about -am (also make) from it. However, in that question, there is only one level of nesting. -am (also make) does not solve my issue since it would build more than I need.

Comment: you may run `mvn -f parent install`, however it is not the same as `mvn install -pl ":parent,:child1,:child2"` (for example in that case it won't resolve grandparent pom)

Comment: That might work! Thank you. The parent/pom.xml has `<parent>` entry that points to grandparent so the grandparent pom should be resolved.