# MyBatis mapper location

Tags: java, mybatis

I have problem with MyBatis configuration within two modules. Project structure look like that:

- DB

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - VideosDAO.class
        - ConnectionFactory.class
        - Videos.class
        - VideosMapper.class
      - resources

        - VideoMapper.xml
        - config.xml
  - pom.xml
- MIXED

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - ArticlesDAO.class
        - Articles.class
        - ArticlesMapper.class
      - resources

        - ArticlesMapper.xml
  - pom.xml

When I have all stuff in DB module I can connect to database and execute SQL but when I want to use ConnectionFactory.class and config.xml from DB module in MIXED module it is not working.

```
### Error building SqlSession.
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document 
instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 
24; Premature end of file.
```

I think problem is in config.xml file within

```
<mappers>
</mappers>
```

I've tried all possibilities from: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers but nothing worked :(
Any ideas how config.xml should look like to allow me to use classes from other module and not duplicate them but in the same time use mapper from other module?

Some of my tries:

```
 <mappers>
    <mapper url="file:///MIXED/src/main/resources/ArticlesMapper.xml"/>
    <mapper resource="VideoMapper.xml"/>
 </mappers>

<mappers>
    <mapper resource="MIXED/src/main/resources/ArticlesMapper.xml"/>
    <mapper resource="VideoMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your maven `MIXED` module depends on maven `DB` module. You need this so that classes and resources are available. Add a dependency into `pom.xml` of the `MIXED` module (have a look for example to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808516/maven-and-dependent-modules))

After you did this classes and resources of the `DB` module are in classpath of the `MIXED` module and you reference them in `config.xml` the same way to you reference resources from the module itself:

```
<mappers>
   <mapper resource="VideoMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```